# Lex and Yacc, how to get values from variables ? (begginner)

Tags: c, yacc, lex

this is my first post and first of all I want to say that I am a total beginner. I'm sorry if my question may seem simple but I really did not find an answer.

I would like to be able to analyze a JSON file that I wrote. Thanks to a tutorial I was able to create my grammar, but I would like to be able to access the corresponding values ​​to use them in C functions, and I don't know how to do it.

Here's my lex and yacc files :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yywrap() { return 1;}
void yyerror(const char* s) {fprintf(stderr,"Error : %s.\n",s);}
%}


%token X Y DIRECTION POINT1 POINTS2
%token INTEGER STRING
%start linkage
%%

linkage: '{' point1 ','  points2 '}' ;

point1: POINT1 ':' point ;
point: '{'
         X ':' INTEGER ','
         Y ':' INTEGER ','
         DIRECTION ':' STRING  {printf("%s",$3);}
        '}';



points2: POINTs2 ':' '[' points2_list ']';
points2_list: points2_ | points2_list ',' points2_ ;
points2_: '{'
         X ':' INTEGER ','
         Y ':' INTEGER ','
         DIRECTION ':' STRING
        '}';


%%

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
yyparse();
}
```

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sample.tab.h"
%}
%%
"\"x\""    return X;
"\"point1\""       return POINT1;
"\"y\""  return Y;
"\"points2\""       return POINTS2;
[0-9]+          return INTEGER;
\"[^\"]*\"       return STRING;
[ \n\t\r]       ;
.               return yytext[0];
%%
```

I don't really understand how variables work, for example to print the direction.
Again, I'm a beginner, I'm not a programmer, I just want to learn more :)

Thanks you

Comment: Look up the use of %union in the yacc documentation, you will want members for the basic data types (strings and integers, as well as an object type and an array of object types. And use flex and bison in peferance to actual lex and yacc if at all possible (they are newer programs that provide the same basic functionality but many more features).

Comment: If your goal is only to analyze your JSON file and eventually process it (using the official JSON grammar). It will probably be much easier to use Python and a lex/yacc implementation such as [ply|https://pypi.org/project/ply/].